# How to delete AppLocker rules with powrshell?

Tags: powershell, applocker

I need to remove AppLocker rules filtered by name. First of all i want to understand how i can delete rules.

I can get current AppLocker rules and i can see, that RuleCollections has method "Delete"

```
$local:Policy = Get-AppLockerPolicy -Local
$Policy.RuleCollections | gm
```

I can delete rules from categories where only one rule

```
$Policy.RuleCollections | Where {$_.Count -eq 1} | foreach {$_.Delete($_.Id)}
```

How can i delete rules from categories where more than one rule?

Comment: Just curious. Why are you scoping the variable as local?  Why are you not just using the ```Remove-AppLockerPolicy``` AppLocker cmdlet to do this vs this delete method?

Comment: local - becouse i do it on a local machine. My system hasn't Remove-AppLockerPolicy cmdlet. Windows 11 22H2 Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment.

```
# Remove all applocker policies for the specified rule type.
Get-AppLockerPolicy -Effective | 
Remove-AppLockerPolicy -RuleType Executable
```

Comment: Result of run this commant is 
"Remove-AppLockerPolicy : The term 'Remove-AppLockerPolicy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.'

Answer (score 0):

```ps1
$LocalAppLockerPolicy = Get-AppLockerPolicy -Local
$RuleCollection = $LocalAppLockerPolicy.GetRuleCollection('exe')
$AppLockerRule = $RuleCollection | ? {$_.PathConditions.Path.Path -eq $PathName}
$RuleCollection.Delete($AppLockerRule.Id)
Set-AppLockerPolicy -PolicyObject $LocalAppLockerPolicy
```